# Accessing non public class from other package

Tags: java

I have a class Logistic in package sequence

```
 package sequence;

 class LogisticSeq  {

 int limit;                                         
 double lamda;                                      
 ArrayList <Double> lseq = new ArrayList <Double>();         

 LogisticSeq(int a, double b, double c) {
    limit = a;
    lseq.add(b);
    lamda = c;      }

 void sequence() throws IOException{

     File file = new File("Sequence.txt");  
     if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
        }}

  public class Logistic {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    LogisticSeq L = new LogisticSeq(50,0.4999,3.9999); 
    L.logisticsequence();
 }
```

How to access the class LogisticSeq from class in other package

Comment: Make it public perhaps.

Comment: You can't, that's exactly the meaning of 'package-private'. Make it `public` or put them in the same package.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I tried to change it to public but i got the error in eclipse and says to define it in its own file.

Comment: @JuanManuel [package-private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) is not the same as private

Comment: @A4L there's no mention whatsoever to package-private in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state:

> @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I tried to change it to public but i got the error in eclipse and says to define it in its own file.

It sounds like you've either got your LogisticSeq class in a file that holds multiple classes or else do not have your class/package name matching your project's package/file structure.

I suggest that you do just what the Java compiler tells you to: Create a LogisticSeq.java file in the sequence package and make sure that the class is public.